# php mysqli select function not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I need some help with the code below, I have simple select function that's not working for some strange reason though everything seems OK and I can't figure out why it prints nothing when called.

```
function getRegNo($vehicleID){
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT regNo FROM vehicles WHERE id = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $vehicleID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($regNo);
    $stmt->fetch();

    return $regNo;
    }
}
```

Any assistance you can offer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$mysqli isn't defined.

Add it as a global at the top of your function.

```
global $mysqli;
```

This relies on you already making $mysqli global which I'm assuming is the case.

Comment: Why is that an issue? What would be the alternative here? Aside from using a global I imagine they'd have to open a new connection in every function that uses a database call which doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: Pass connection object as a parameter to the function for example.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why using a global is an issue? Most of the work I do uses frameworks where a database object is always global.

Comment: exactly function getRegNo($vehicleID, $mysqli){

Comment: Could you give any example of PHP framework using global variables? It always becomes an issue when amount of code grows. That's why we have programming patterns.

Comment: CodeBird was right, passing the $mysqli parameter was the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

once try this (assuming the id is an integer)

```
 $stmt->bind_param('i', $vehicleID);
```

and set `$mysqli` as `global` or pass it as an parameter to the function